# The effectiveness of SIMD Work Group, Block Size to the kernel execution time on the FPGA

Tags: opencl, fpga, hpc

I have run many experiments for the different sizes of the OpenCL matrix multiplication example using different configurations of Block Size and SIMD Work Group on the FPGA. The results show that the execution time decrease in relation to the block size but it doesn’t decrease in relation to the SIMD size.

I am wondering why the Block Size effects and decrease the execution time while SIMD Work Group does not have any effect on the execution time?

Comment: This question is unclear to me because of the used terminology. I might be able give an answer if I would know what "Block Size" and "Work Group" are in Matrix multiplication. Also you do not specify how you convert OpenCl to FPGA code. A lot of the quality of the resulting FPGA code depends on that process. (I suspect the slow down is due to the lack of automatic pipe-lining in that process)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
SIMD_WORK_ITEMS :This value tells the compiler how many work-items in the work-group in a SIMD fashion. In the context of matrix multiplication, this value indicates how many output elements will be computed in a SIMD manner. BLOCK_SIZE must be a multiple of SIMD_WORK_ITEMS.